# How to index a function list output for use in another function?

Tags: r, indexing, subset, lapply, purrr

I am using lapply() to take in a list of 2 files and compose() to apply multiple functions. The two functions being applied will load in the data from the file (list of 2 lists of dates) and then select the last element in the list.

The issue arises when I try to select the last element in each list of dates. Rather than the tail() function outputting one date, it outputs the whole list. I find that I can index the loaded data by data[[1]] for the first list and data[[2]] for the second one to get the correct final element. I don't know how to do this within the context of lapply(), compose(), and partial().

Here is the original code:

```
dates <- 
  list(
    from = lapply(file_last_dates,
                  purrr::compose(as.Date, purrr::partial(sum,1))),
    up_to = lapply(tamsat_retrieved_dates,
                   purrr::compose(purrr::partial(tail,n=1), st_load_rds))
    )
```

which outputs the following structure.

```
List of 2
 $ from :List of 1
  ..$ file_last_dates.rds: Date[1:1], format: "2023-01-01"
 $ up_to:List of 2
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ ST/rfe/raw/ssa/tamsat-v3.1/dekadal/retrieved_dates.rds: Date[1:1419], format: "1984-01-10" "1984-01-20" "1984-01-31" "1984-02-10" ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ ST/rfe/raw/ssa/tamsat-v3.1/daily/retrieved_dates.rds: Date[1:14396], format: "1984-01-01" "1984-01-02" "1984-01-03" "1984-01-04" ...
```

On the other hand, the following code

```
tail(st_load_rds(tamsat_retrieved_dates)[[1]],n=1)
```

and

```
tail(st_load_rds(tamsat_retrieved_dates)[[2]],n=1)
```

give me the output I want, below.

```
"2023-05-31"
```

The structure of st_load_rds(tamsat_retrieved_dates) is

```
List of 2 $ ST/rfe/raw/ssa/tamsat-v3.1/dekadal/retrieved_dates.rds: Date[1:1419], format: "1984-01-10" "1984-01-20" "1984-01-31" "1984-02-10" ... $ ST/rfe/raw/ssa/tamsat-v3.1/daily/retrieved_dates.rds : Date[1:14396], format: "1984-01-01" "1984-01-02" "1984-01-03" "1984-01-04" ...
```

and the structure of file last dates is

```
List of 1 $ file_last_dates.rds: Date[1:1], format: "2022-12-31"
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of `file_last_dates` and `tamsat_received_dates` using `dput(head(...)` please?  A minimal reproducible example will make it much easier for people to help you.  Additionally, please avoid using screenshots of data or output - copy and paste into a code block in your question.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I don't quite know what that means but file_last dates is a <List of 1 $ file_last_dates.rds: Date[1:1], format: "2022-12-31"> while tamsat_recieved_dates is a List of 2 file pathways that is read by the function `st_load_rds`

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen The structure of st_load_rds(tamsat_retrieved_dates) is List of 2
$ ST/rfe/raw/ssa/tamsat-v3.1/dekadal/retrieved_dates.rds: Date[1:1419], format: "1984-01-10" "1984-01-20" "1984-01-31" "1984-02-10" ...
 $ ST/rfe/raw/ssa/tamsat-v3.1/daily/retrieved_dates.rds  : Date[1:14396], format: "1984-01-01" "1984-01-02" "1984-01-03" "1984-01-04" ...

Comment: Thanks for getting the info - can you please edit it into your original question - it doesn't  paste well into comments!

Answer (score 1):

With a structure like this ...

```
dates <- list(from = list(Sys.Date() + 1:3),
              to = list(Sys.Date() + 10:13)
              )
```

```
$from
$from[[1]]
[1] "2023-06-27" "2023-06-28" "2023-06-29"


$to
$to[[1]]
[1] "2023-07-06" "2023-07-07" "2023-07-08" "2023-07-09"
```

... you could `Map` or `purrr::map`:

```
## note the double brackets:
dates |> Map(f = \(li) tail(li[[1]], 1))
## $from
## [1] "2023-06-29"
## 
## $to
## [1] "2023-07-09"
```

... or recursively apply a function:

```
dates |> rapply(f = \(li) tail(li, 1)) |> as.Date(origin = '1970/01/01')
##         from           to 
## "2023-06-29" "2023-07-09"
```

(Mind that, for unsorted dates, `tail` will return the last date while `max` will return the latest.)